# installing scikit learn on ubuntu

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn, cross-validation, updating

I am trying to use cross_val_predict function to get the accuracy of a binary classifier made by using scikit-learn.

The command I am using is:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named model_selection
```

I am using scikit learn of version 0.14.1.
I tried to update scikit learn version through this command:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

But the installation does not complete.the warning is:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]

_import_umath(void)

can any body help me with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but it seems a problem of tools/dependencies, you have 2 choices:

1) Worst (Install tools and dependencies):

```
$ Sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

And then try to update, again

2) Best (Use Anaconda):

> [Install Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), use easily multiple python versions and difrerent envs, and be happy with scikit or any other scientific package.

---

> Edit (04/25/17): 
>   If your choice was the first option, try update scikit this way:

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did the first option. every thing is upgraded. but still I can not import sklear.model_selection.

Comment: Ok, you can have the 2 options. Anaconda isolates (intact) you original python, thus, you can make a test: 1) install anaconda and create a venv like your current ($ conda create -n p27 pytnon=2.7.13), 3) Activate p27 ($ source activate p27)  4) Install requirements and test your program.

Comment: @yas.f You said everything is upgraded. Can you check the version of sklearn now?